# User history actions - The proper way to store in django models

Tags: django, django-models, models

My users are employers who can make actions like sending messages to candidates, share their resume with other and write a review about a candidate.

For that I've created 3 seperate models, one for each action:

```
class Share(models.Model):
    user          = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser, related_name="shares")
    shared_user   = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser, blank=True)
    to_email      = models.EmailField()
    message       = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.user, self.to_email)

class Review(models.Model):
   user    = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser)
   to_user = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser, related_name='reviews')
   review  = models.TextField(blank=True)
   rating  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, blank=True)
   date    = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.user, self.to_user)**

class MessageSent(models.Model):
     user    = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser, related_name="messages")
     to_user = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser)
     message = models.TextField()
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return '%s - %s' % (self.user, self.to_user)
```

I would like to be able to list all employer's history actions.
What is the best way to do so?

I was thinking about 2 options :

1. Retrieving related info from each model into the template ( user.reviews_set.all , user.share_set.all ,etc...) And then sort them all by date via jquery/javascript.
2. Create another history model that will contains all user actions. But I'm not sure how to do it...

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get inspired from django's admin log `from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry` or use it if it matches your requirements.
[Checkout this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py)

Comment: So what you are basically saying is that I should keep the models above and just add another history model that will be similar to the LogEntry model, right?

Comment: yep, make sure you have django.admin in your installed_apps

Comment: I'm glad for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick and dirty idea: all your models have a lot in common. You can subclass a base model (Message) and retrieve a simple history (i.e. without separation messages from shares and reviews) by models.Message.objects.all()

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user          = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser)
    to_user       = models.ForeignKey(BatitoUser, blank=True)
    message       = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return '%s - %s' % (self.user, self.to_user)

class Share(Action):
    to_email      = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.user, self.to_email)

class Review(models.Model):
   rating  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, blank=True)
```

There is still question if there is same quick and dirty way to separate messages by type in history

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I actually use additional models to store history actions between users (calling, interview...) which doesn't have a message field. So will it make sense to create a base model with only user, to_user fields? Also, maybe adding a "type" field to the base model will help to differentiate between history actions?

Comment: after some time I think it is not really a good idea. Yet it is still possible to inherit everything from one base model, implementing history using it would be a big cludge. As @Mounir advised, LogEntry and creating ones in post_save signal would be much more clean and straightforward